# size of long data type changes in 32 bit & 64 bit compilers

Tags: c, operating-system

The size of long data type changes on 64 bit compiler. On 32-bit compiler both int & long has 4 bytes size. Whereas in 64-bit, it changes to 4 & 8 bytes. Why is this difference?

Comment: It's up to the compiler.

Comment: Why would you expect them to be the same??!

Comment: On 64-bit Microsoft Windows, they are both 32-bit, 4 bytes. In Linux, `long` is the same size as a pointer.

Answer (score -2):

What determines the size (number of bits) of data is the width of the internal registers of the microcontrollers. 
The software are always a step behind the hardware, and is not unusual you have a 64-bit processor and compile your programs with a 32-bit compiler or even a 16-bit compiler (I still have 16-bit software running on 64-bit processors).

The ideal case is when you have a compiler with features target to get the full power of the processor you have.

Today, despite the majority of computers has 64-bit processor, not all compilers are ready to use the full power of hardware.

According to Microsoft, their tools continue to differentiate the 32 to 64 bit code, only on the width of pointers, and maintaining the width of data.

However, nothing prevent you to use a compiler that take full advantage of the 64 bits of the internal registers of the processors.